# If else condition in RecyclerView onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set up a if else statement on my `onBindViewHolder()` such that it checks for status, then sets text and text color depending on the status found.

I've tried but it just gives me the results of the first condition on every item in the `RecyclerView`.

Here is my code for the `Adapter`:

```
    public class PreviousSettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PreviousSettingsAdapter.PreviousSettingsViewHolder> {
private List<Setting> SettingsModelList;
private Context context;

public PreviousSettingsAdapter(Context context, List<Setting> SettingsModelList) {
    this.SettingsModelList = SettingsModelList;
    this.context = context;
}

public class PreviousSettingsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.date)
    TextView date;
    @BindView(R.id.Setting_id)
    TextView SettingId;
    @BindView(R.id.status)
    TextView status;

    public PreviousSettingsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PreviousSettingsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.placed_Setting_items, parent, false);
    return new PreviousSettingsViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PreviousSettingsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Setting singleSetting = SettingsModelList.get(position);
    holder.date.setText(singleSetting.getCreatedAt());
    holder.SettingId.setText("Setting Id: " + String.valueOf(singleSetting.getId()));


    boolean paymentStatus = singleSetting.getConfirmed();
    boolean fulfilledStatus = singleSetting.getProcessed();

    if (paymentStatus && !fulfilledStatus ) {
        holder.status.setText(R.string.processed);
        holder.status.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange);

    } else
     if (!paymentStatus && !fulfilledStatus) {
        holder.status.setText(R.string.unchanged);
        holder.status.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed);

    } else if(paymentStatus && fulfilledStatus){
        holder.status.setText(R.string.delivered);
        holder.status.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen);


    }else{
        holder.status.setText(" ");
    }


    }


@Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return SettingsModelList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: have u tried to print yout payment status and fulfilled status in the bind view holder? It might be logical error

Comment: You want to change `status` text color?

Comment: `holder.status.setTextColor(context.getResources.getColor(R.color.colorOrange));` set the color like this in your conditions. In your code you are not setting color.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and kindly see that the `paymentStatus`  and `fulfilledStatus` values.As you said, it might be going into the if loop with those conditions satisfying.

Comment: Both status are evaluating to false yet that's not the case from the database